# PHP Calendar Function only showing events on months 10, 11 and 12

Tags: php

I have a Calendar function and the problem is that it only displays events for months 10, 11 and 12 none before that are shown.

So if on the URL I add:

```
calender.php?month=01&year=2013 TO calender.php?month=09&year=2013, No events will be displayed.
```

BUT if I do:

```
calender.php?month=10&year=2013, calender.php?month=11&year=2013 or calender.php?month=12&year=2013, these will display fine.
```

I cannot find the part of the code responsible for this bug, any ideas anyone? :o/

Here is the Full function code:

```
<?php

        /* draws a calendar */
        function draw_calendar($month,$year,$events = array()){

          /* draw table */
          $calendar = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">';

          /* table headings */
          $headings = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
          $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row"><td class="calendar-day-head">'.implode('</td><td class="calendar-day-head">',$headings).'</td></tr>';

          /* days and weeks vars now ... */
          $running_day = date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
          $days_in_month = date('t',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
          $days_in_this_week = 1;
          $day_counter = 0;
          $dates_array = array();

          /* row for week one */
          $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';

          /* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
          for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
            $days_in_this_week++;
          endfor;

          /* keep going with days.... */
          for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):


            ////$calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';

            /* add in the day number */
            if($list_day < 10) {
                $list_day = str_pad($list_day, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            }


            $calendar.= ".$list_day.";

            $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;



            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

              /* add in the day number */
              $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';

              $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;



              if(isset($events[$event_day])) {

                  //var_dump($events[$event_day]);

                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
               ////$calendar.= '<div class="event"><a href="cal_popup.php?title='.$event['title'].'" target="blank" title="'.$event['title'].'">'.$event['title'].'</a></div>';
                   $calendar.= '<div class="event" id="selector"><a href="#" target="blank" title="'.$event['title'].'">'.$event['title'].'</a><div class="overlayOuter"><div class="overlayInner"></div></div></div>';

                    //var_dump($events[$event_day]);


                }
              }
              else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
              }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $calendar.= '</div></td>';
            if($running_day == 6):
              $calendar.= '</tr>';
              if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
              endif;
              $running_day = -1;
              $days_in_this_week = 0;
            endif;
            $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
          endfor;

          /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
          if($days_in_this_week < 8):
            for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
              $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
            endfor;
          endif;

          /* final row */
          $calendar.= '</tr>';


          /* end the table */
          $calendar.= '</table>';

          /** DEBUG **/
          $calendar = str_replace('</td>','</td>'."\n",$calendar);
          $calendar = str_replace('</tr>','</tr>'."\n",$calendar);

          /* all done, return result */
          return $calendar;
        }

        function random_number() {
          srand(time());
          return (rand() % 7);
        }

        /* date settings */
        $month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
        $year = (int)  ($_GET['year'] ? $_GET['year'] : date('Y'));

        /* select month control */
        /*$select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
        for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
          $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
        }
        $select_month_control.= '</select>';*/

        $select_month_control = '<select name="month" id="month">';
            for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++) {
        $select_month_control.= '<option value="'.str_pad($x, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT).'"'.($x != $month ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$x,1,$year)).'</option>';
}
$select_month_control.= '</select>';

        /* select year control */
        $year_range = 7;
        $select_year_control = '<select name="year" id="year">';
        for($x = ($year-floor($year_range/2)); $x <= ($year+floor($year_range/2)); $x++) {
          $select_year_control.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $year ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.$x.'</option>';
        }
        $select_year_control.= '</select>';

        /* "next month" control */
        $next_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 12 ? $month + 1 : 1).'&year='.($month != 12 ? $year : $year + 1).'" class="control">Next Month &gt;&gt;</a>';

        /* "previous month" control */
        $previous_month_link = '<a href="?month='.($month != 1 ? $month - 1 : 12).'&year='.($month != 1 ? $year : $year - 1).'" class="control">&lt;&lt;   Previous Month</a>';


        /* bringing the controls together */
        $controls = '<form method="get">'.$select_month_control.$select_year_control.'&nbsp;<input id="cal_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" style="padding:1px 4px;margin:2px 0;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$previous_month_link.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$next_month_link.' </form>';

        /* get all events for the given month */
        $events = array();
        //$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM table1 WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date LIKE '$year-$month%' AND active = 1";

        $query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM table1 WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date BETWEEN '$year-$month-1' AND '" . date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1")) . "' AND active = 1";



        $result = mysql_query($query,$db_link) or die('cannot get results!');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

          $events[$row['date']][] = $row;

         //var_dump($events);
        //echo ($query);


        }

        echo '<div style="clear:left;float:left;width:100%;margin-top:30px;">';
        echo '<h2 style="float:left; padding-right:30px;">'.date('F',mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)).' '.$year.'</h2>';
        echo '<div style="float:left;">'.$controls.'</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo draw_calendar($month,$year,$events);
        echo '<br /><br />';


    ?>
```

Comment: what happens if you change 09 to 9

Comment: I've tried that but still doesn't sound any events

Comment: Oke, can you check the month before it goes into the function

Comment: Yeah, I've added: $TheMonth = $_GET['month']; echo $TheMonth; before the function and it's displaying 09

Comment: Also `$year-$month-1` -> change to `$year-$month-01`. (okay, so that's on the day rather than the month, but if this is about leading zeros, we should try to be consistent throughout)

Comment: I've tried changing all $year-$month-1 to $year-$month-01 but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: My suggestion is to do `echo $query` to see what the actual query string is that is being called. This might show you the problem immediately. If it doesn't, try copying+pasting the query into your faviourite DB querying tool, and try testing it to see what it actually gives. That should be enough to get you going with debugging the problem.

Comment: OK, I've echoed $query and this is what I've getting: SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM table1 WHERE user_id = '23' AND date BETWEEN '2013-9-01' AND '2013-09-30' AND active = 1

Comment: I can see the problem but no idea how to fix it. The FROM DATE is 2013-9-01 but should be 2013-09-01

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried to $query and pasted it into the database SQL and run it...It actually returns 3 record but none are shown in the calender so it's not the query it's just not displaying it :o/

Comment: Basically $event['title'] is not displaying for months other than 10, 11 and 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To problem is you make a integer of the month that means if you have 09 it will be 9 because 09 is not a integer.

To fix this, change this line:

```
$month = (int) ($_GET['month'] ? $_GET['month'] : date('m'));
```

to

```
$month = isset($_GET['month']) ? $_GET['month'] : date('m');
```